# How to convert a time series data which can be fed to a Machine Leanring model for unsupervised learning?

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

I am very new to time series data. I am working with server data and want to classify if the bunch of server times are healthy or not.

My data looks like this in pandas

```
+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-------+
|  ID   | timestamp | IP_address |   event_type   | usage |
+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-------+
| 12xcv |       456 |     123573 | server_load    |  56.0 |
| 12xcv |       457 |     123573 | server_process |  59.0 |
| 12xcv |       459 |     123573 | unload         |  43.0 |
| 23vbz |       461 |     123573 | server_load    |  78.0 |
| 23vbz |       461 |     123573 | unload         |  78.0 |
+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-------+
```

My questions are:

1. I want to use unsupervised clustering algorithm. How do I convert this data so that I can use something like k-means with two clusters such that one cluster denotes healthy and other denotes unhealthy.
2. What other unsupervised methods exists for classification in time series data?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think you would have to define what is a "healthy" server in order for us to help you. Also, how do you know this is an unsupervised problem? If your data indicates "healthy" servers then you should also be able to find "unhealthy" ones. If that's the case, then wouldn't this become a supervised problem?

Comment: Thanks for replying. There is no metric given for healthy server and so I thought I can do some kind of clustering and get two clusters. Then based on those clusters I will figure out if they are unhealthy or healthy. There is no label provided and hence the problem is unsupervised.